# C# Start JAVA process failed - StackOverflowError

Tags: java, c#, mono, jvm

I'm trying to start JAVA process from C#.

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "java",
            Arguments = "-Xss512k -jar vnu.jar -jar some_file.html",
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
var proc = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

The java is trying to run the [HTML5 Validator JAR](https://github.com/validator/validator), but it failed with message:

```
StackOverflowError while evaluating HTML schema.
The checker requires a java thread stack size of at least 512k.
Consider invoking java with the -Xss option. For example:
   java -Xss512k -jar ~/vnu.jar FILE.html
```

Any idea what is wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to disable the STDOUT/STDERR redirect and now the process is running OK. It seems the problem is to redirect JAVA output. Need to investigate more.

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "java",
            Arguments = "-Xss512k -jar vnu.jar -jar some_file.html",
            RedirectStandardError = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
var proc = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Comment: That may sound obvious, but have you tried launching the process from the command line, using the same arguments?

Comment: Yep - it is working